# Error in control of Type FileUpload while adding new row in a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am using fileUpload control inside the gridview . I used the following code but it is giving exception while executing.

Code part where i got exception :

```
FileUpload file = (FileUpload)gridFile.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("fileUpload1");
```

Exception:
 Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload' to type 'FileUpload.FileUpload'.

Code:

```
    protected void AddNewRow()
      {
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow dr = null;
            if(dt.Rows.Count >0)
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
                for(int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count-1;i++)
                {
                    FileUpload file = (FileUpload)gridFile.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("fileUpload1");

   dt.Rows[i]["Browse"] = file.ToString();

}
            }
                gridFile.DataSource = dt;
                gridFile.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: while casting use System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload file=(System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload)gridFile.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("fileUpload1");

Comment: try send data as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while casting use

```
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload file=(System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload)gridFile.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl‌​("fileUpload1");
```

Answer (score 0):

That message tells you that runtime type of your object is different from that you are trying to cast. You need make sure that your variable file is System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload not FileUpload.FileUpload. You probably defined class that have the same name like that one in framework. Use full qualified name types to resolve that.

Edited:
Mysterio11 gave you an example. You can also try to use different namespace if you don't want to use full type names.